# How to use google translate to change detected language by click

Tags: jquery, html, google-translate

How to use google translate to change language to selected language by click,
its like click on "english-text" then google auto translate the page to english wanna do it to all language (note : I dont want google translate element that appears select language. I want select language to be hidden hope that, code be helpful to understand :

```js
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en'
  }, 'translator');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#en").click(function() {
    /*using google translate to auto change language to english*/
  });
  $("#ar").click(function() {
    /*using google translate to auto change language to arabic*/
  });
  $("#ru").click(function() {
    /*using google translate to auto change language to russian*/
  });
  $("#sp").click(function() {
    /*using google translate to auto change language to spanish*/
  });
  $("#fr").click(function() {
    /*using google translate to auto change language to french*/
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>M-code</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="translator">
    <hr class="bg-light">
    <h5 class="text-light">Languages</h5>
    <hr class="bg-light">
    <p id="en" class="text-light">English</p>
    <p id="ar" class="text-light">Arabic</p>
    <p id="ru" class="text-light">Russian</p>
    <p id="sp" class="text-light">Spanish</p>
    <p id="fr" class="text-light">French</p>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```